# Why does my string value pass knockout validation, but integer value does not?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-validation

Using knockout 2.2.1 with latest knockout-validation.js.

See the following jsfiddle for a working example of my issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/tbstudee/keRPY/4/

As you can see when being loaded with existing data the integer value is not passing validation, but the string value is. This is only happening when the viewModel is initialized with existing data.

I know the problem is in my isValid flag since commenting it out removes the validation error on load.

```
self.isValid = ko.computed(function () {
    return ko.validation.group(
        self,
        {
            observable: true,
            deep: true
        }).showAllMessages(true);
}, self);
```

What can I do to work around this, other than seed my viewModel with strings instead of ints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`maxLength` and `minLength` are for strings, for numbers you need to use `min` and `max`, otherwise the validation ends up casting the value as a string. Take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tyrsius/LcSWG/)

```
self.myInt = ko.observable(data.myInt).extend({
        required: true,
        number: true,
        min: 100000,
        max: 999999
    });
```

Comment: This was actually also canceling out another problem, since you had `number: true` on your string value, but it was valid due to the `maxLength` check.